# Android change build target from 4.1 to 3.1

Tags: android

im trying to change my project build target from 4.1 to 3.1 in android studio.

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

to

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="12" />
```

and in my project structure i change SDKs Build target to Android 3.1.
When i try and run the project in my AVD setup for 3.1 i get project not compatible with AVD.

The main errors i get in my code is:

```
    Bundle bundle_animation = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(
            MainActivity.this, R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2).toBundle();
    startActivity(startNewGame, bundle_animation);
```

I know makeCustomAnimation wasnt introduced until 4.1...but how can i fix this...can i add classes from 4.1 and add it to 3.1sdk??? or what method was used before ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation...any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have discovered, `ActivityOptions` wasn't added until API level 16 and there is nothing equivalent provided in the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).

So, you have two options:

1. Continue targetting version 16 of the SDK and just change the `minSdkVersion` to 12. Then you can use an if statement to check whether the app is running a version that has the `ActivtyOptions` class at runtime. e.g.

   ```
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
       // Start activity with a custom animation
       Bundle bundle_animation = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2).toBundle();
       startActivity(startNewGame, bundle_animation);
   }
   else {
       // No custom animations :(
       startActivity(startNewGame);
   }
   ```

   Note that might get lint warnings, you can add annotations to ignore the error.
2. If you **must** target version 12 of the SDK, then you may be able to still run these methods on newer devices by using reflection. I won't elaborate on this now as it's quite complicated... but it's still an option.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey big thanks for the reply...seeing that im not that advanced at android development, ill stick to option 1:)...iv tried to implement your solution, but im getting no lint warning...Just "cannot resolve symbol ActivityOptions"

Comment: Did you change `android:targetSdkVersion` back to 16 in your AndroidManifest.xml? That should change the version you build with back to 4.1 and make `ActivityOptions` visible again. I don't use Android studio so I'm not sure if there's something else you need to do to change the SDK version you build against.

Answer (score 0):

use this to let the new activity (DetailActivity.class) come in from the left side over the current activity.

like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzgGGWpRES0

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyApplication.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activtiy_pet_detail_right_slide_in, R.anim.activtiy_pet_detail_left_slide_out);
```

instade of:

```
Bundle bundle_animation = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(
            MainActivity.this, R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2).toBundle();
    startActivity(startNewGame, bundle_animation);
```

it works for < 16 API
hope it helps :)

Comment: Could you please add some description to your answer?